# Can electron be polarized?

Tags: electromagnetism, electrons, quantum-electrodynamics

I know that electrons split into two beams when passed through a non-homogeneous magnetic field.
But is electron polarized when passed through some substance? For example, light the polarization can be done with the help of polaroid.

Answer (score 0):

No, one cannot polarize electron beams by passing them through a material.  [Scattering in material randomizes the momentum (direction) of the electrons in the beam but not their spin, so the beam depolarizes.](http://www.slac.stanford.edu/cgi-wrap/getdoc/slac-pub-4656.pdf)  In the best case your material is so thin you get almost no collisions and the beam doesn't lose any polarization.

Comment: Well, there is spintronics. And GMR (giant magnetoresistance) depends on spin-polarized currents. There is spin-polarized STM from chromium tips. And there are Mott scattering spin analyzers.

Comment: The GMR effect falls of dramatically at room temp, because of collisions, and doesn't use an external electron source.  Spin-polarized STM methods are a source, not a passive element like a light polarizer/polaroid.  Mott scattering doesn't leave you with a beam, but it does come closest to an effect like a polarizer.